# Word cutting off between lines in button

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have buttons that can hold multiple lines of text (title). However, occasionally, the words or numbers would cut off between lines. It is also good to note that I am getting the text for the button's title from a Database.

How do I make it so that the word would just go down to the next line?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Can you post samples of what you have tried? An MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful here in more quickly identifying the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button's Line Break mode to "Word Wrap" in your storyboard.

If setup by code, set the `lineBreakMode` of the button's `titleLabel` property to `.byWordWrapping`.